# Symfony2 intercept direct access to a specific uploads folder

Tags: php, symfony, controller, routes, restrict

I have a Symfony project with an uploads folder. Within that folder I have sub-folders that I would like to restrict access to some of. eg.

```
- small (allow)
- medium (allow)
- large (dis-allow)
- original (dis-allow)
```

How can I restrict access to the 2 folders above and then intercept the call to a controller so I can check credentials before serving the file?

Answer (score 0):

Symfony use user www-data (like Apache) to access files on your server. You can disable access for this user.

If you want to control access for all of your users in Symfony app, you must create users in your OS and then give them permissions.

Comment: Interesting. I was thinking that this might be a .htaccess thing?

Comment: Someone else can take other answer, maybe.